# Component life cycle

Tags: angular, typescript, lifecycle

There was another problem, I do not know what to do with it.
I think that the problem is with the life cycle of the component, but there are no ideas how to fix it.

**articles-list.components.ts**

```
export class ArticlesListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) {
  }

  @Input() articlesList;

  articleInfo: IArticleInfoArray;
  articlesTitles: string[];
  allArticlesInfo: any[] = [];
  averageLength: number;

  static getUrlInfo(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles='
      + searchQuery + '&prop=info&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getArticlesTitle() {
    this.articlesTitles = this.articlesList[1];
  }

  getArticlesInfo() {
    for (const title of this.articlesTitles) {
      this.articleService.getArticlesInfo(ArticlesListComponent.getUrlInfo(title))
        .subscribe(
          (data: IArticleInfo) => {
            this.articleInfo = {
              ...data,
              query: {
                pages: [Object.values(data.query.pages)[0]]
              }
            };
            this.allArticlesInfo.push([this.articleInfo.query.pages[0].touched, this.articleInfo.query.pages[0].length]);
          }
        );
    }
  }

  getAverageLength() {
    let sum = 0;

    for (const length of this.allArticlesInfo) {
      sum += length[1];
    }

    this.averageLength = sum / this.allArticlesInfo.length;
  }
}
```

**articles-list.component.html**

```
<div class="articles-list pt-2" *ngIf="articlesList">
  <div class="ml-2">
    <h4>По запросу <small class="text-muted query">"{{ articlesList[0] }}"</small>
      найдены статьи:</h4>
    <h6>Количество найденных статей: {{ articlesList[1].length }}</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="articles-list__block" *ngFor="let article of articlesList[1]; let i = index">
    <div *ngFor="let link of articlesList[3]; let k = index" [hidden]="i != k">
      <a class="articles-list__link" [attr.href]="link">{{ article }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="articles-list__description mt-2 mb-2" *ngFor="let description of articlesList[2]; let j = index" [hidden]="i != j">
      <div *ngIf="description !== ''; else missingSnippet">{{ description }}</div>
      <ng-template #missingSnippet>Краткое описание отсутствует</ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="articlesList">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
    (click)="getArticlesTitle(); getArticlesInfo(); getAverageLength()">Дополнительная информация</button>
  <ng-container *ngIf="averageLength">
    {{ averageLength }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

The problem is that the value `averageLength` appears only after the second button is pressed.

I tried to use functions `getArticlesTitle(); getArticlesInfo();` in the method `ngOnInit`, but then there will be an error `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

What should I do? How do I get the value immediately when the component is initialized `averageLength`?

Comment: because you are doing everything on button click. you are calling the functions, and then the data comes and assigns to the variable. before calling the function getAverageLength() , averageLength  is undefined. 
besides,  this.articlesTitles = this.articlesList[1]. you are trying to access an item of the list but there is no item in the list. so the value in index 1 is undefined

Comment: @SadidKhan How to fix it? Rebuild the interface?

Comment: what is the use of this button? what do you want? can you create a stackblitz so that others can easily find what is wrong?
what this button does? do you want to get data from server after button click?

Comment: @SadidKhan I want after pressing the button to display the value of the variable `averageLength`

Comment: @SadidKhan [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euc9j8)

Comment: @SadidKhan In general, I don’t really need this button; I just need the value of this variable to appear when this component appears.

Comment: I think the first comment is the key. :). As that comment narrates everything, you can give an upvote that also @llya nizovcev

Comment: @SadidKhan Thank you, it works, but this value is not updated, it always remains the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, call those function in ngOnInit().

```
export class ArticlesListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) {
  }

  @Input() articlesList;

  articleInfo: IArticleInfoArray;
  articlesTitles: string[];
  allArticlesInfo: any[] = [];
  averageLength = 0;

  static getUrlInfo(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles='
      + searchQuery + '&prop=info&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getArticlesTitle();
    this.getArticlesInfo();
  }

  getArticlesTitle() {
    this.articlesTitles = this.articlesList[1];
  }

  getArticlesInfo() {
    for (const title of this.articlesTitles) {
      this.articleService.getArticlesInfo(ArticlesListComponent.getUrlInfo(title))
        .subscribe(
          (data: IArticleInfo) => {
            this.articleInfo = {
              ...data,
              query: {
                pages: [Object.values(data.query.pages)[0]]
              }
            };
            this.allArticlesInfo.push([this.articleInfo.query.pages[0].touched, this.articleInfo.query.pages[0].length]);debugger;
            this.calculateAvaerage();
          }
        );
    }
  }

  calculateAvaerage(){
    let sum = 0;
    for (const length of this.allArticlesInfo) {
      debugger;
      sum += length[1];
    }

    this.averageLength = sum / this.allArticlesInfo.length;
  }
}
```

but here inside `getArticlesTitle()` method you are trying to acces `this.articlesList[1]`. This one will throw an error because this.articlesList in undefined as the data is not populated yet.

To fix this, you need to update search component a bit.

Add `*NgIf` in html of search component html and initialize articles as an empty array so that we can use the length property to determine whether we load the `app-article-list` component.

so, update **search.component.ts** with -

```
articles: any[] = [];
```

and **search.component.html** with -

```
<app-articles-list  *ngIf="articles.length > 0" [articlesList]="articles">
</app-articles-list>
```

so, `app-article-list` component will load when articles has some item in it.

Here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9mnfz)